# Можно ли в yandex-tank изменить время "connection timeout"?

Tags: яндекс-танк

Я работаю с "тяжёлым" сайтом, который открывается довольно долго, и хотел бы узнать, можно ли изменить время, которое *Яндекс.Танк* считает за "connection timeout"?
И какое это время по умолчанию?

Answer (score 4):

Вам нужно явно указать строку `time_periods` в секции `[aggregator]` в конфигурационном файле.

Запросы не уложившиеся в максимальное значение в этой строке принудительно закрываются танком и маркируются как "connection time out".

Время ожидания в танке по умолчанию равно 10 секундам.

Описание опций модуля aggregator можно посмотреть [тут](https://yandextank.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html?#aggregator).

Советую не просто добавить в конец строки максимально нужное вам значение, например 60s, а заполнить отрезок промежуточными значениями, т.к агрегатор в танке по умолчанию высчитывает статистику раскладывая запросы по "корзинкам": "от n-1 до n-й величины",  "от n-й до n+1й величины" итд. где n - значения заданные в time_periods.

Comment: я так понимаю что этот параметр секции aggregator стал deprecated ? я не вижу его в документации

Comment: в секции  [phantom] можно задать таймаут явно timeout=<Xs>, корзинки агрегатора переопределить сейчас нельзя.